# Wordpress localhost plugin installation

Tags: linux, wordpress, ftp

i installed wordpress by following wiki. It's up and running but when i'm trying to install a plugin it says this;

[image]

i've no knowledge about such a thing but i tried to enter my user and olsa root info but nothing happened. Any help will be appreciated!

*arch user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add this to wp-config file

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

if it not works. perhap you need to fix wordpress file & folder permission

- [Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)
- [Proper WordPress Filesystem Permissions And Ownerships](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/)